# Manipulating line spacing in LaTeX

Tags: latex, whitespace

I have a block of text in a quotation.  Some of that text will be in a very small font (`\scriptsize`) and some much bigger (`\Large`).  My problem is that the letters in the big font push right up against the letters in the line above.  This effect is unacceptably distracting to the reader.  (Trust me; for my use, it is.)

My question, then: how do I insert space to push apart the lines so that the large text does not scrape against the text above it?

Comment: Perhaps I should have been more specific:  I'm looking to add space between lines within one paragraph.

\vspace{} appears to add space before or after a paragraph, but not between lines within it.  Am I wrong?

Thanks again.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can specify `\vspace` in postscript points. This will give you very fine-grained control.

or...

you can use the `setspace` package: `\usepackage{setspace}` then use the commands:

- `\singlespacing`
- `\onehalfspacing`
- `\doublespacing`

or...

you can use `\linespacing{factor}`: Use

- `\linespread{1.3}` for "one and a half" line spacing, and
- `\linespread{1.6}` for "double" line spacing.

Normally the lines are not spread, so the default line spread factor is 1.

Comment: +1. I recommend `\usepackage{setspace}`. If the suggested commands don't give you fine enough control, you can use `\setstretch{factor}`. You can use the `\setstretch` in multiple places in your document (i.e. it doesn't have to be a global setting) and it scopes properly (i.e. if you put it in a group, it only takes effect within that group).

Comment: Both \usepackage{setspace} with \setstretch{factor} and \linespread{factor} followed by \selectfont worked for me.

Thanks for helping out a novice.

Answer (score 5):

There are myriad methods, but in paper writing, I often use a \vspace{0.75cm} after the separating newline (I'm metric, so pick a unit you like).